# "Eдинственная, кто поддержалa его" or "eдинственная, кто поддержал его"

Tags: глаголы, род

Consider the two following phrases:

- она единственная, кто поддержалa его
- она единственная, кто поддержал его

Which one is correct according to official rules (whatever we mean by *official*. Let's say any grammar reference someone can provide as evidence).

On one hand, according to the rules, we always need to make the verb agree with the noun according to gender. On the other hand, we can treat the overall construction as a reduced version of "[из тех, кто] - i.e. with a de-facto interpretation of "кто" as an abstract collective pronoun.

However, when I'm thinking about this and trying to come up with a list of examples and counter-examples, such as:

- она единственная, кто знала всё об этом
- она единственная, кто надела вечернее платье
- она единственная, кто съела весь обед

Personally for me, the masculine version sounds slightly off, but any personal preferences I may have, would have to defer to actual established rules, hence my question.

Answer (score 3):

> On one hand, according to rules we always need to agree the gender of
> the verb with noun.

This rule is not absolute. In some cases, the gender of the verb differs from the gender of the noun. *Врач пришел/пришла. Большинство соседей уехало/уехали.*

There is, alas, no unambiguous rule for the pronoun кто, because in Russian кто refers to different pronouns (вопросительное, относительное, неопределенное). Nevertheless, the average rule is "verb in the masculine gender". Yes, sometimes you get something unusual like *В своей семье Елена единственная, кто родил двойню.*

[1. При подлежащем – вопросительном местоимении кто глагол-сказуемое ставится в форме единственного числа, а в прошедшем времени – в мужском роде, независимо от числа производителей действия и их принадлежности к мужскому или женскому полу, например: Кто присутствовал на последнем занятии? Кто из сотрудниц нашего отдела записался в кружок кройки и шитья?](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html#id-43%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%C2%A7187%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146097/discussion-on-answer-by-atoma-e--a--or-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no prescriptive rule for that.

Shvedova et al., *Русская грамматика*:

> Местоимения *кто* и *что* не дифференцируют лица по признаку пола. Эту функцию может принимать на себя соотносительное слово: *Все так ярко рисуется взору, Что не верится мне в эту пору, Чтоб не мог увидать я и той, Чья душа здесь незримо витает, Кто под этим крестом почивает (Некр.)*. Отношение к полу может быть выражено в самом придаточном предложении формой глагола-сказуемого: *Немногое понадобилось Вадиму Петровичу, чтобы кончить с колебаниями, — это немногое был отыскавшийся след Кати. Так на песке у прибоя отпечаток босой женской ноги заставит иного человека написать в воображении целую повесть о той — прекрасной, — кто здесь прошла под шум волн большого моря (А. Н. Толст.)*.

> Употребление слова *который* в качестве замены местоимения *кто* объясняется его способностью формально выражать род и число и, таким образом, информировать о принадлежности лица к мужскому или женскому полу, а также характеризовать его с точки зрения единичности/неединичности: *Нынче те, которые больше всех и в самом деле скучают, стараются скрыть это несчастие как порок (Лерм.); Я та, с которой вы говорили утром по телефону (разг. речь).*

A brief search in the corpus shows [75 uses](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Ct8DErsDCrgDChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluEqsBClMKA2xleBJMCkrQtdC00LjQvdGB0YLQstC10L3QvdGL0Ll80LvRjtCx0L7QuXzQv9C10YDQstGL0Ll80L/QvtGB0LvQtdC00L3QuNC5fNGC0L7RggoKCgRmb3JtEgIKAAoOCgVncmFtbRIFCgMoZikKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoAEnIKCQoDbGV4EgIKAAoQCgRmb3JtEggKBtC60YLQvgoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoACgwKBGRpc3QiBAgBEAESfwoJCgNsZXgSAgoACgoKBGZvcm0SAgoACh4KBWdyYW1tEhUKEyhWKSAmIChwcmFldCkgJiAobSkKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoACgwKBGRpc3QiBAgBEAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQEwAA==) of the masculine vs [33 uses](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=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) of the feminine.

Comment: Не ясно как это относится к данному случаю, кроме примера текста Толстого, в котором стоит аж два тире и запятая между той и прекрасной. Кроме того: "той — прекрасной, — кто здесь прошла под шум волн большого моря". "Той - прошла," - поэтому женское склонение, могло все быть иначе.

Answer (score 2):

In ruscorpora.ru, after "единственная, кто" there are 20 cases of the masculine and six cases of the feminine, so it seems there's no definite rule, but the masculine is more common.

Answer (score 1):

Она единственная его поддержалa.
Она единственная, кто его поддержал.

Мысль можно выразить и так и сяк. Если глагол женского рода, то вариант с «кто» вообще неуместен, звучит как калька с иностранного.
Она единственная (из всех), кто его поддержал.
Так звучит полная конструкция. И всё согласовано. А правило дала Atomа.
В состав «всех» входят лица и мужского и женского пола.

Соответственно:

Она единственная, кто знал об этом всё.

Она единственная, кто надел вечернее платье.

Она единственная, кто съел весь обед.

Или:

Она единственная знала об этом всё.

Она единственная надела вечернее платье.

Она единственная съела весь обед.

Answer (score -3):

*Она, единственная, поддержала его/ она единственная, кто поддержал его* - поддержал согласовано с кто, усложнение, возможно, оправданное контекстом, но вообще достаточно бессмысленное. Возможно, это ответ на вопрос:

-Кто поддержал его?

-Она - единственная, кто поддержал его. (возможно, есть смысл ставить тире)

То есть усложнение может быть оправдано предыдущим вопросом. Но я бы такие конструкции без нужды не употреблял, так как акцент с "она" перемещается на "кто" из-за чего следует "её" обезличивание.

Из [литературы](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClIqGAoICAQQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCLwotCisKA3JlcRIkCiIi0LXQtNC40L3RgdGC0LLQtdC90L3QsNGPLCDQutGC0L4iMAE=):

*"С единственной, кто ласки презирала..."* Блок. Единственное женское склонение, "единственной" здесь, скорее всего местоимение или замена с "ней".

*"..сестра, единственная, кто осталась в жизни от детства, кто прошел через всю жизнь, что связано любовью семьи, рода, крови."* Пильняк. Не определился куда склонять. Возможно: "сестра, кто осталась.." и "единственная, кто прошёл".

*"Вы подумайте: она единственная, кто не придал значения всей этой истории.."* Окуджава.

В большинстве остальных примеров согласование с "кто" через окончание мужского рода.

Comment: я не в числе заминусовавших ваш ответ, но просто хочу дать понять почему он заминусован - строго говоря, это не ответ на заданный вопрос

Comment: @shabunc ну я попробую найти ссылку, но по мне слово "кто" и оборот через кто здесь лишний и не оправдан. Это в лучшем случае какой-то разговорный вариант, но это не литературный русский язык. Скорее всего калькирование.